# How to Get exact format MS word paragraph Copy and paste with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Right Now using **Range.Text** is formatting into plain Text (removing Bold, Underline etc) . need to be same as RTF format or original Format while using copy and Paste through below code

below code works for create missing field in Array and creates as same

```
    Sub replacemissing3()
Dim myarray As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim line_text As String
Dim datainbtw As String
Dim missing_image As InlineShape
Dim check As Boolean
check = False
datainbtw = ""
i = 0
myarray = Array("ØQ:", "ØQuestion:", "ØQuestionHindi:", "ØOption:", "ØOptionHindi:")

For Each singleline In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
line_text = singleline.Range.Text

If check Then
If Not InStr(singleline.Range.Text, "Ø") And Trim(singleline.Range.Text) <> "" Then
datainbtw = datainbtw + singleline.Range.Text

If singleline.Range.ShapeRange.Count > 0 Then
Set missing_image = singleline.Range.ShapeRange(1).ConvertToInlineShape
datainbtw = Replace(datainbtw, "/", " ")
datainbtw = datainbtw + "Ømissingimage"
End If

If singleline.Range.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
Set missing_image = singleline.Range.InlineShapes(1)
datainbtw = Replace(datainbtw, "/", " ")
datainbtw = datainbtw + "Ømissingimage"
End If

End If
End If

If InStr(line_text, "ØQ:") Then
line_text = "ØQ:"
End If


If InStr(line_text, "ØQuestion:") Then
line_text = "ØQuestion:"
End If

If InStr(line_text, "ØQuestionHindi:") Then
line_text = "ØQuestionHindi:"
End If

If InStr(line_text, "ØOption:") Then
line_text = "ØOption:"
End If

If InStr(line_text, "ØOptionHindi:") Then
line_text = "ØOptionHindi:"
End If
 
line_text = Trim(line_text)

If InStr(line_text, "Ø") = 1 Then

If InStr(singleline.Range.Text, "Ømissingimage") Then
missing_image.Select
Selection.Copy
singleline.Range.PasteSpecial
GoTo lbl1
'Exit For
End If

If line_text <> myarray(i) Then
singleline.Range.Text = myarray(i) + vbNewLine + datainbtw
i = i - 1
'Exit For
End If

If myarray(i) = "ØOptionHindi:" Then
i = -1
End If
i = i + 1
lbl1:
datainbtw = ""
check = True
End If

Next singleline
 
End Sub
```

datainbtw  placing plain Text instead Bold

Example :
ØQuestion:
12 In the word ‘**BRISKLY**’, how many pairs of the letters have the same number of letters between them in the word as in alphabet?

ØQuestionHindi:

12 In the word ‘BRISKLY’, how many pairs of the letters have the same number of letters between them in the word as in alphabet?

Comment: Read up on .Rang.FormattedText.

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: The only time your code copies and pastes anything it is an image. All the rest of your code is working with strings. Strings only hold text, not formatting.

Comment: Yes noticed String .. can you suggest how to handle this

Comment: If you need to keep the formatting your only option is to use [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find)

Comment: @Gajendran  You obviously didn't read up on .Range.FormattedText